# get response before navigating to next route

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I want to post some data to api when im navigating to a new route. I also want the next route to be loaded after i get the response from the api call .

My router event subscription :

```js
     this.subscriptionGrade = router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart))
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.submitScore();
      });
```

Im unsubscribing on ngOnDestroy:

```js
     ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptionGrade.unsubscribe();
      }
```

Submit score function:

```js
      submitScore() {
        const score = { score: this.scoreForm.get("score").value };
        if (this.scoreForm.get("score").value) {
          this.learningContentService
            .gradeAssignment(this.selectedAttempt, score)
            .subscribe((res) => {});
        }
      }
```

Now im able to submit score on route change, but it navigates to new route before i get a response from the submit score api. I want to route to next page only after the response as i want the updated data in the next page. How to implement this? Note that the user can navigate to any route he chooses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use guards `canActivate` and `canDeactivate`, first one when a new route should be loaded the second one when a route is going to be left.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoadGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(protected readonly http: HttpClient) {}

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.get('MY_URL').pipe(
          tap(response => {
            // do something with response
          }),

          // allowing route
          mapTo(true),

          // in case if response not 200 we don't allow to load the route.
          catchError(() => of(false)),

        );
    }
}
```

and the same for can `canDeactivate`.